# Three.js - calculating relative rotations

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, scenegraph

I have a `THREE.Scene` with two meshes added, `meshA` and `meshB`, each of which has been rotated in different ways. My goal is to remove `meshB` from the scene and re-add it as a child of `meshA`, while preserving its global position and rotation -- in other words, the position and rotation of `meshB` should appear the same before and after this code.

My current, almost working attempt is as follows:

```
var globalOffset = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( meshB.position, meshA.position );
var localOffset = meshA.worldToLocal( meshB.position );

var rotationOffset = meshA.quaternion.clone().inverse();
var rotation = meshB.quaternion.clone().multiply( rotationOffset );

scene.remove(meshB);
meshA.add(meshB);

meshB.position = localOffset;
meshB.rotation.setFromQuaternion(rotation);
```

The positioning works fine; the rotation only works if both `meshA` and `meshB` have been rotated around the same axis -- if `meshA` and `meshB` have been rotated around different axes, `meshB` appears to change rotation before and after this code.

Any ideas how I can correct the code above (or an idea for a different approach) so that `meshB` still has the same "global" rotation before and after being removed and re-added to the scene?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove `meshB` from the scene and re-add it as a child of `meshA`, while preserving its global position and rotation.

You can do that like so:

```
meshA.attach( meshB );
```

three.js r.109