# Clone rotation from child and assign it to another child of a different parent in THREE.JS

Tags: rotation, three.js, rotational-matrices, quaternions

I have a parent Object containing a child Object

```
var parent1 = new THREE.Object3D();
parent1.rotation.set(1,2,3);
scene.add(parent1);

var child1= new THREE.Object3D();
child1.rotation.set(0.5,0.1,0.3);
parent.add(child1);
```

and another parent containing another child.

```
var parent2= new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(parent2);

var child2= new THREE.Object3D();
childC2.rotation.set(3,1.15,2);
parent.add(child2);
```

Now I want to give `child2` the same rotation as `child1` by rotating it's `parent2`.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557341/three-js-get-world-rotation-from-matrixworld), I can get the world-rotation from my original `child1` like this:

```
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
child1.matrixWorld.decompose( new THREE.Vector3(), quaternion, new THREE.Vector3() );
```

and apply it to my `parent2` like this:

```
parent2.quaternion.copy( quaternion );
```

Now `parent2` has the same rotation like the original `child1`, but I want it's child `child2` to have have the same rotation like `child1` (only by modifing `parent2`)

I think this can be done by getting the difference of the world-rotation from `parent2` and `child2` and substracting this from the world-rotation of `child1`, to correct the offset generated by the rotation of `child2`.
But my knlowledge of quaternions and matrices is to bad to get it working.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laurid/uocx3bua/33/), to understand my problem.
[image]
Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

I tried the approach of WestLangley. If my Objects are only rotated around x-axis it works like this ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laurid/uocx3bua/36/))

```
//calculate the relative rotation of child2
THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child2, parent2, scene );
var rotX=parent2.rotation.x-child2.rotation.x;
var rotY=parent2.rotation.y-child2.rotation.y;
var rotZ=parent2.rotation.z-child2.rotation.z;
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child2, scene, parent2 );

//combine the relative rotation of child2 and the 'world' rotation of child1
THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child1, parent1, scene );
rotX+=child1.rotation.x;
rotY+=child1.rotation.y;
rotZ+=child1.rotation.z;
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child1, scene, parent1 );
parent2.rotation.set(rotX,rotY,rotZ);//assign it to parent2
```

If my Objects are rotated around x,y,z this is NOT working anymore ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laurid/uocx3bua/37/)). Is this a problem with gimbal lock? Do I need to do the calculation with quaternions instead of Euler Objects?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002984/three-js-calculating-relative-rotations/23003560#23003560

Comment: Using the 'Scene.Detach' / 'Scene.Attach' methods I can only make it work for rotations on x-axis. Is this a Bug in Three.js (68) ?

Comment: You can't subtract Euler rotations componentwise. See if this fiddle does what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/715v2hr1/. If so, I'll post an answer. The fiddle is a little tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to rotate a parent object so that the parent's child has a particular orientation, and you want that particular orientation to match the orientation of a child object of a different parent. Whew!

Here is one way to do that:

```
// detach the children from their parents and add them to the scene
THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child2, parent2, scene );
THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child1, parent1, scene );

// here is the tricky part: add the second parent as a child of its former child
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( parent2, scene, child2 );

// copy the first child's rotation, and make sure the matrix is updated   
child2.rotation.copy( child1.rotation );
child2.updateMatrixWorld( true );

// detach the parent from the child and add it to the scene
THREE.SceneUtils.detach( parent2, child2, scene );

// put the children back where the were before   
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child2, scene, parent2 );
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child1, scene, parent1 );
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/715v2hr1/

three.js r.68